# Manpulating DataContext in Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I have a really small application where I have a list of jokes, everything is working properly but I have to re-set DataContext everytime I want to display the information in the TextBlock. The TextBlock changes in the SAME page, I only want to change the joke ID to get the new joke.

```
 private IList<Jokes> data;
    Array variable;
    private int count;

    // Constructor
   // ObservableCollection<Jokes> = new ObservableCollectoin<Jokes>;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        JokeRepository countryRepository = new XmlJokeRepository();
        data = countryRepository.GetCountryList().ToList<Jokes>();
        DataContext = countryRepository.GetCountryById(3);
             }
 private void nextIconClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Random rand = new Random();
        int holder = rand.Next(1, count);
        DataContext = data.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == holder);
               }
```

Where in my XAML I have the {Binding Description} property working correctly, but I really feel this redundant and useless. Is there another way to work this without having to reset DataContext everytime although I still use the same variable/page?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a property such as `CurrentJoke`, then set your `DataContext` to that.

Then you could just update that property and fire a `NotifyPropertyChanged` event, which will refresh the `TextBox` with the latest data from your `CurrentJoke` property.

Here's an (untested but pretty close) code sample:

```
public class Page : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string currentJoke;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string CurrentJoke
    {
        get
        {
            return currentJoke;
        }
        set
        {
            if ( currentJoke == value )
                return;

            currentJoke = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( new PropertyChangedEventArgs( "CurrentJoke" ) );
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( this.PropertyChanged != null )
            this.PropertyChanged( this, e );
    }
}
```

In your XAML, set use the same `{Binding CurrentJoke}` syntax you used for the `Description`. The `DataContext` is probably already set correctly for the whole page if you have one field databinding correctly.

Comment: How can I set the DataContext to that ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, going to try it

Comment: You're welcome. It might be worth reading up on the MVVM pattern, if you haven't already. I don't always use it in my apps, but it helps you understand how to use databinding effectively.

Comment: Yeah, was reading Jesse Liberty's tutorials but TBH for starters it gets really complicated and didn't really understood how to use that Messenger etc

Comment: Agreed, and even when you get your head around it, it's sometimes overkill. Good luck!